# How to programatically open document in lecture mode in word 2013?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop, readonly

I'm trying to open programatically via `VB.Net` a word document in readOnly mode but in order to modify this document it has to be opened in Page View. It is what Word 2010 automatically does but not Word 2013 who open it in Lecture Mode.

Is there a way to avoid this? An open it in Page View Mode instead of Lecture Mode?

When opened :
[image: When opened :]
Where I have to click to have what I want:

[image: Where I have to click to have what I want:]

How word should be open :
[image]

Comment: did you try to set `ReadOnly parameter` to true in `Documents.Open method`? Here is the beginning of the syntax: `expression.Open(FileName, ConfirmConversions, ReadOnly, ...`

Comment: Yep but this `readonly` only influence on the attributs of the document it doesn't change the view of Word.

Comment: I don't know if my screenshots explain a little more my situation...